# Finding Mesh Changes/Difference from an existing 3DR

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango, 3d-reconstruction, csg

Say a Tango (Unity) device is used in a controlled room, where all objects and walls are stationary and pre-known.
You take a 3DR scan of the room, and have a good ADF.

***How could you approach detecting/tracking only new/changed objects?***
Eg a single chair is added to the room.

Has anyone done this piece of work previously?  Or can you suggest the way you would approach the problem?

So far my best idea is to use a "constructive solid geometry" library on a new mesh generated, compared to the pre-captured mesh... although it looks like it might be too expensive to run in real-time alongside everything else..

Comment: Check out PCL.   http://pointclouds.org/